# Making / resolve "generically" instead of to an index file in Apache + mod_mono

Tags: apache-2.2, mono

I recently tried deploying my extremely "odd/custom" web application and I'm having some problems.

Basically, in my code at Global.asax I have

```
if(context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath=="/"){ //doesn't work(yields 404 error for index.aspx)
  Response.Write("foo);
}
if(context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath=="/test"){ //does work
  Response.Write("bar");
}
```

At the moment, I am just using the simple auto configuration for Apache and mod_mono. The only thing I added was making it use .Net 2.0 and I added

> ForceType application/x-asp-net

How can I make it so that it won't try to resolve / to some index file, and instead let it be handled by the application?

Note: This works perfectly using xsp alone in my debugging environment

Comment: Does mod_rewrite to a single file work for you?

Comment: @matt what do you mean to a singl file?

Comment: Something like RewriteRule /* /Global.asax (syntax unchecked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing away with auto configuration and instead using http://go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/ to generate me an Apache configuration